# Back button with previous page history with applied jquery state at last moment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a counting table within a div say "tablediv" like below. When I click on a particular number, it gives me the number of students in an other table in a div. Name it "studentdiv".

On click a number, I am hiding "tablediv" and I want to show "studentdiv".

Which have student list table, on click  name of the perticular student(link) redirecting to other controller, which shows student whole data in this page.

I have a back button on click it goes back with this link: `<a href="javascript: window.history.go(-1)">back</a>`. It goes to the previous page by reloading.

Where count table is shown instead of student list table. (The last state is "tablediv" is hidden and "studentdiv" shown.)

My requirement is, when a user click back in student whole data page, I need to show the student table which is present at last state, not count table.

My count table is this:

```
           | a1|b1 | c1| d1|   
        ---|---|---|---|---|---
         a | 12| 4 | 6 |32 |   
        ---|---|---|---|---|---
         b | 7 | 2 |13 |45 |   
        ---|---|---|---|---|---
         c |23 | 54| 5 | 7 |   
        ---|---|---|---|---|---
         d |78 | 43| 67| 43|   
        ---|---|---|---|---|---
```

The student table:

```
         Name   | Gender  |religio| caste  |
        --------|---------|-------|--------|-----------
         jon    |  male   | -     |   -    |
        --------|---------|-------|--------|-----------
         sumith |  male   |    -  |  -     |
        --------|---------|-------|--------|-----------
         rita   |  female |  -    |   -    |
        --------|---------|-------|--------|-----------
```

Comment: You need to at least make an attempt at writing the code.

Comment: i tried many attempts and searched google

Comment: with window.location.replace() and window.history.pushstate but i am not getting

Comment: No one is just going to write your code for you. If you have any programming experience, you at least need to try. Your answer requires several different areas of knowledge.

Comment: I am fresher with recently working on this php

Comment: What I could understand in your post, I fixed, but it is far from being enough. First, use [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) checklist to avoid the worst grammar mistakes. Second, use round, clear sentences. Your post is to me partially unclear, and unclear questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

create main div showing the 'tablediv' and the create another div that is hidden.

```
<div id="studentdiv_id" style="display:none;">
```

and

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                                            $("num_id").click(function(){
                                                $("main_div_id").empty();
                                                    $("studentdiv_id").clone().show().appendTo("main_div_id");
                                            });
                                        });
```